# When using variable in sed it replaces entire line, instead of just the matching string

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, variable

I'm new to bash and I've been trying to understand other posts that's similar, but I'm just not sure if they do the thing I need.

When I don't use variables and just put in what I want to search for and replace with, it works fine. But when I pass variables the scripts also removes the string "host1". This part is preceded by a for loop looking for the file which contains "host1". The arg1, 2 and 3 is $1, $2, $3.

```
input="$f"   

while read -r line  
 do  
 sed "/"$arg2"/ s=192.168.10.*="$arg3"="  

done < "$f"
```

I want to just replace the ip in the line containing the string "host1"

```
10.10.10.10 host1
```

Comment: What are `$arg2` and `$arg3`? Usually, command line arguments in bash scripts are denoted by `$1`, `$2` etc.

Comment: This is unclear. Please edit your question and add a) the input file, b) the desired output file and c) format the sed commands as code to show *exactly* what they look like (indent them four spaces). In particular, they seem to be missing  a final `/` without which my (GNU) sed complains that the expression is untermitated.

Comment: For some reason i created
arg1= $1
arg2=$2
arg3=$3

Because i didnt got sed to interpret them correctly at first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$arg2` is set to `host1` and `$arg3` is set to `10.10.10.10` then both your `sed` commands will remove `host1` from the output.

The problem is because you are matching `192.168.10.*`, the `.*` at the end will match anything up to the end of the line and replace it with `10.10.10.10`.

Try:

```
arg2=host1
arg3=10.10.10.10
sed "/${arg2}/ s/192\.168\.10\.[0-9]\+/${arg3}/" /path/to/file
```

Comment: Cheers @Freddy, updated the answer